# How to change the class for all elements with list of ids?

Tags: jquery, each

Initial state is that I have an array of ids [45, 3, 678] and a div tag with lots of elements inside, they are nested and all of them have a unique ids. I need to add class "selected" only for those elements, whose ids are in the array of ids. How can I achieva that?

```
<div id="parent-class">
  <details id=1>
    <ul id=2>
      <details id=3></details>
      <details id=4></details>
      <details id=5></details>
      ...
    </ul>
  </details>
  <details id=56>
    <ul id=57>
      <details id=58></details>
      <details id=59></details>
      <details id=60></details>
      ...
    </ul>
  </details>

</div>



$('div#parent-class').ready(function () {
    var options = [45, 3, 678];

    /* Here I need to loop through all children and assign class for those elements whose id is in array options*/
    $('div#parent-class').children().each(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      if ($.inArray(id, options)) $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
  });
```

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: You can't use numerics for `id=` you might want `data-id=` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/2181514

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you know how to create `for` loop?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: "*.children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree*" https://api.jquery.com/children/ change to `$("div#parent-class").find("*").each...`

Comment: Side note, in case it matters: `<details>` is not supported in IE (all versions) and Edge (upto v18). See here: https://www.caniuse.com/#search=details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/2181514)  commented out you need your ids to contain at least one alpha caracter so i suggest you change your ids, for the loop you simply use the attribute selector to select the elements in your array

```js
$('div#parent-class').ready(function () {
    var options = [56, 3, 60];
    options.forEach(function(v,i) {
      $('[id="item_'+v+'"]').addClass('selected');
      //or $("#item_" + v).addClass('selected');
    })
  });
```

```css
.selected{border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent-class">
  <details id="item_1">
    <ul id="item_2">
      <details id="item_3"></details>
      <details id="item_4"></details>
      <details id="item_5"></details>
      ...
    </ul>
  </details>
  <details id="item_56">
    <ul id="item_57">
      <details id="item_58"></details>
      <details id="item_59"></details>
      <details id="item_60"></details>
      ...
    </ul>
  </details>

</div>
```

Comment: If you're using `id=item_` then you can use `$("#item_" + v)`